# How to display 3 records in a single row of table

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, mysql

In the code below, I tried to show three records in the card in single row of a table. However, instead it displays only one record per row.

Also, I'm required to pass the item code to a modal popup but couldn't understand how to do that. Despite searching, I can't get complete clarification on how to do this.

My Complete code is as follows:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">

<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <link href="../css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="../css/business-casual.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:300italic,400italic,600italic,700italic,800italic,400,300,600,700,800" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Josefin+Slab:100,300,400,600,700,100italic,300italic,400italic,600italic,700italic" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    <style>
        .card {
            box-shadow: 0 4px 8px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
            transition: 0.3s;
        }
        .card:hover {
            box-shadow: 0 8px 16px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
        }
        .container {
            padding: 2px 16px;
        }
        input[type=text],
        input[type=password] {
            width: 100%;
            padding: 12px 20px;
            margin: 8px 0;
            display: inline-block;
            border: 1px solid #ccc;
            box-sizing: border-box;
        }
        /* The Modal (background) */

        .modal {
            display: none;
            /* Hidden by default */

            position: fixed;
            /* Stay in place */

            z-index: 1;
            /* Sit on top */

            left: 0;
            top: 0;
            width: 100%;
            /* Full width */

            height: 100%;
            /* Full height */

            overflow: auto;
            /* Enable scroll if needed */

            background-color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
            /* Fallback color */

            background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
            /* Black w/ opacity */

            padding-top: 60px;
        }
        /* Modal Content/Box */

        .modal-content {
            background-color: #fefefe;
            margin: 5% auto 15% auto;
            /* 5% from the top, 15% from the bottom and centered */

            border: 1px solid #888;
            width: 80%;
            /* Could be more or less, depending on screen size */
        }
        .close {
            position: absolute;
            right: 25px;
            top: 0;
            color: #000;
            font-size: 35px;
            font-weight: bold;
        }
    </style>
</head>

<body>
<?php

$cnt=0;
$rslt = mysqli_query($conn,"SELECT Name,Size,Style FROM productinfo");
if(!$rslt)
{
    die(mysqli_error($conn));
}
else
{
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($rslt))
    {
        echo "<table width='100%'>";
        if($cnt==0)
        {

            $cnt = $cnt + 1;
            echo "<tr>
                  <td width='30%'>
                  <div class='card'>
                  <img src='upload/download.jpg' alt='Avatar' style='width:100%' >
                  <div class='container'>
                    <h4><b>".$row['Name']."</b></h4> 
                    <p>".$row['Size']."</p> 
                  </div>
            </div>";
            ?>
            <button onclick="document.getElementById('id01').style.display='block'" style="width:auto;">Inquiry</button>
            <?php

            echo "</td>";
    }
    else
    {
        echo "<td width='30%'>
              <div class='card'>
              <img src='upload/"."download.jpg"."' alt='Avatar' style='width:100%' >

              <div class='container'>
                <h4><b>".$row['Name']."</b></h4> 
                <p>".$row['Size']."</p> 
              </div>
            </div>
            ";
            ?>
            <button onclick="document.getElementById('id01').style.display='block'" style="width:auto;">Inquiry</button>
            <?php

            echo "</td>";
        if($cnt==2)
        {
            $cnt=0;
            echo "</tr>";
        }
        else
        {
            $cnt = $cnt + 1;
        }               
    }
}
echo "</table>";
}
?>

<div id="id01" class="modal">
<div align="center">
<form action="ViewProd.php" method="post" role="form" class="modal-content animate" ><br/>
<div class="imgcontainer">
      <span onclick="document.getElementById('id01').style.display='none'" class="close" title="Close Modal">&times;</span>
      <img src="upload/download.jpg" alt="Avatar" class="avatar">
    </div>
 <table border="0px" cellpadding="1" cellspacing="0">
    <tr >
        <td width="25%">
            &nbsp;&nbsp;Name
         </td>            
     <td width="100%">&nbsp;&nbsp; <!--<input type="text" tabindex="1" id="Icode"  />-->
     <input tabindex='1' accesskey='i' name='Nm' type='text' maxlength='200' id='Nm' width="100%" required="required"/>
     </td>
</tr>
<tr >
    <td width="25%">
        &nbsp;&nbsp;Company Name
    </td>
    <td>
    &nbsp;&nbsp; <input type="text" tabindex="1" name="Compnm" id="Compnm" border="0" required="required"/>
    </td>
</tr>
<tr >
    <td width="25%">
        &nbsp;&nbsp;How do you Know about us?
    </td>
    <td> 
        &nbsp;&nbsp; <input type="text" tabindex="1" id="HowKnow"  name="HowKnow" />
    </td>
</tr>
<tr >
    <td width="25%">
        &nbsp;&nbsp;Email Address  
    </td>
    <td> 
        &nbsp;&nbsp; <input type="text" tabindex="1" id="EmailAdd" name="EmailAdd" required="required"/>
    </td>
</tr>
<tr >
    <td width="25%">
        &nbsp;&nbsp;Contact No.  
    </td>
    <td> 
        &nbsp;&nbsp; <input type="text" tabindex="1" id="Phone" name="Phone" />
    </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td width="25%">
        &nbsp;&nbsp;City  
    </td>
    <td> 
        &nbsp;&nbsp; <input type="text" tabindex="1" id="City" name ="City"/>
    </td>
</tr>
<tr >
    <td width="25%">
        &nbsp;&nbsp;Message
    </td>
    <td> 
        &nbsp;&nbsp; <input type="text" tabindex="1" id="Remarks"  name="Remarks"/>
    </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td colspan="2" align="center">
        <button type="submit">Submit</button>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
</form>
</div>
</div>
<script>
// Get the modal
var modal = document.getElementById('id01');
// When the user clicks anywhere outside of the modal, close it
window.onclick = function(event) {
    if (event.target == modal) {
        modal.style.display = "none";
    }
}
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: What is the primary key id column of your `productinfo` table?

Answer (score 0):

BTW, Where is your database connection?

Anyway...

1) On your first loop, inside the first condition, you increment `$cnt` by one, then on the condition below before the loop repeats, `else` will also increment `$cnt`. I also made your code lesser, but with the same display.

```
echo '<table width="100%">';

while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($rslt)){

    if($cnt == 0){

        echo '<tr>';

    }

    echo '        <td width="30%">
                      <div class="card">
                          <img src="upload/download.jpg" alt="Avatar" style="width:100%" >
                          <div class="container">
                              <h4><b>'.$row['Name'].'</b></h4> 
                              <p>'.$row['Size'].'</p> 
                          </div>
                      </div>';
            ?>
                      <button class="view-data" data-artid="<?=($row['id'])?>" onclick="document.getElementById('id01').style.display='block'" style="width:auto;">Inquiry</button>
            <?php

    echo '</td>';

    if($cnt == 2){
        $cnt = 0;
        echo '</tr>';
    } else {
        $cnt = $cnt + 1;
    }

}

echo '</table>';
```

2) Your second concern requires more work. You will need to use [Ajax](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/) for this.

First, lets assign a `class` attribute and set the `id` of each data to each of their corresponding button, which you will notice on the code on item #1. You also have to indicate the `id` column on your query (lets assume that you call named it `id`, just replace it with the right one):

```
$rslt = mysqli_query($conn,"SELECT id, Name,Size,Style FROM productinfo");
```

Then lets create the script that will listen to the button when it is clicked:

```
$(document).on('click', '.view-data', function(){

    var elem = $(this),
        id = elem.attr('data-artid');

    $.ajax({
        method: 'POST',
        url: 'getdata.php',
        data: {'id' : id},
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function(result){

            $("#Nm").val(result.Name);
            $("#Compnm").val(result.CompanyName); /** REPLACE NECESSARY COLUMN NAME **/
            /** DO THE REST HERE WITH THEIR RESPECTIVE COLUMN NAME **/

        }
    });

});
```

We have to create the `getdata.php` file, which you'll notice in our script above. That is where we will get the corresponding data of the clicked button.

```
<?php

    /*** INCLUDE YOUR DB CONNECTION HERE ***/

    $stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM productinfo WHERE id = ?");
    $stmt->bind_param("i", $_POST['id']);
    $stmt->execute();
    $meta = $stmt->result_metadata();
    while ($field = $meta->fetch_field()) { 
        $params[] = &$row[$field->name]; 
    }

    call_user_func_array(array($stmt, 'bind_result'), $params);            
    while ($stmt->fetch()) {
        foreach($row as $key => $val) { 
            $productinfo[$key] = $val; 
        }
    } 
    $stmt->close();

   echo json_encode($productinfo); /** WE WILL THROW THIS DATA BACK TO THE AJAX REQUEST **/

?>
```

Be mindful of your console log to look for errors when testing this.

Comment: Product Details will not be displayed in the modal popup I need to get some input from the user based on the selected product in that modal Popup and save it into mySql db as an inquiry